# Primereact Dropdown with alternative array key format

Tags: reactjs, primereact

When I use the Dropdown with the array, but the item is not with format `{value, label}`, e.g.: `{tag, name}`, the default value is not selected and the `onChange` value return the whole object, instead of the `tag` value. I tried with `dataKey="tag"` but seems like it doesn't work
The sample code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/primereact-kvewe

Comment: Maybe a codesandbox working example of this behavior can help to understand your issue

Comment: You mean data is not constant?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, this is the link to sample code
https://codesandbox.io/embed/primereact-kvewe
If I replace the object format and using the `dataKey`, the default selection value is not selected.